# Biblatex - customize apa style

Tags: biblatex, apa-style, apa6

I know it is not suggested to mess with the default of the APA style, but I consider a minor change.

I would like to add a colon behind the "In" for `@incollection`/`@inproceeding` items. Does anyone know where this "In" is hidden in the `apa6`-style files, so that I can add a colon? Couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard styles have the command `\intitlepunct` for that, but `biblatex-apa6` hard-codes the space

```
\newbibmacro*{in}{%
  \ifbool{bbx:in}%
    {}%
    {\global\booltrue{bbx:in}%
     \bibcpstring{in}\setunit{\space}}}
```

You can easily change that (note that we use `\printunit` and not `\setunit` in line with upcoming `biblatex` changes, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/943 and https://github.com/plk/biblatex/pull/944)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=apa6, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addcolon\space}
\renewbibmacro*{in}{%
  \ifbool{bbx:in}%
    {}%
    {\global\booltrue{bbx:in}%
     \bibcpstring{in}%
     \printunit{\intitlepunct}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,pines,gaonkar:in,westfahl:space}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Gaonkar, D. P. (2001). On alternative modernities. In: D. P. Gaonkar (Ed.), Alternative modernities (pp. 1–23). Durham: Duke University Press.]

Comment: Fantastic! THX :)